# Why is there no android.annotation package found in android doc?

Tags: android

I can found that the annotion SuppressLint in whose full name is android.annotation.SuppressLint,but no android.annotation package found in android doc

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an oversight. If you enter "android.annotation" in the search area of the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html#), you'll see "android.annotation" pop up as one of the options, but if you click on it, you get an "Error 404" message.

It turns out somebody has already [reported this "bug"](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42318&q=android.annotation&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).